# How to capture picture of client and save it on server using flask?

Tags: python, opencv, flask

```
from flask import Flask, Response
import cv2
class Camera(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

  def get_frame(self):
    ret, frame = self.cap.read()
    return open('stream.jpg', 'rb').read()


app = Flask(__name__)

def gen(camera):
  while True:
    frame = camera.get_frame()
    yield (b'--frame\r\n'
      b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/')
def video_feed():
  return Response(gen(Camera()),
  mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame') 

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

I want to capture every frame per second and save it to file upto 20 images how can I do it? Can Anyone suggest proper code for that?

Comment: Is that server or client code? Looks like both.

Comment: do you want to save each image you get as a frame from camera and then save it in a bundle of 20 ?

Comment: It is server code. if you access this server it capture the frames every second which are in raw data format are encoded to image format return to client

Comment: Do you want to capture image from the client browser and store it on your server? 
Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47368422/3126337