# How can I capture an image from a client side web cam and save it to the server please? I am using Python with Flask, running on a Heroku instance

Tags: javascript, python, heroku, webcam

How can I capture an image from a client side web cam and save it to the server please?

- I am using Python with Flask, running on a Heroku instance.
- I have made my code run perfectly with OpenCV (CV2) locally on my laptop
- The problem is CV2 cannot see the client side webcam. There are no webcams in the data center and the data center is not where the user is !

The original code I wrote can be seen below:
https://github.com/iainonline/ImageRecognitionAndWebsiteLookup

The part I am struggling with is capturing a snapshot from the users webcam, so I can do the text recognition on the saved file.

I want to be able to have the webcam capture a snapshot and create a file 'image.jpg' on the server.

```
# The name of the image file to annotate
file_name = os.path.abspath('image.jpg')

# Loads the image into memory
with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()
```

I have been able to find Javascript that will initialise the users webcam and take a snapshot.

You can see that running here:
https://iainonline.github.io/

The code is here:
https://github.com/iainonline/iainonline.github.io

The problem I have is I cannot seem to find a way to take the snapshot from the webcam and save that as a file to the Heroku server. I have searched really hard for a solution but I cannot find this exact problem replicated anywhere else. I am open to using something other than Javascript if that is simpler.

Thank you for reading this far and any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer which works locally. However I cannot yet make it work on Heroku. See the stack overflow link below:-

[How do i take picture from client side(html) and save it to server side(Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46860816/how-do-i-take-picture-from-client-sidehtml-and-save-it-to-server-sidepython?rq=1)